# To find similar words (strings) in two files

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have to validate the similarity of word 1 in file 1 with word 2 in file 2 and so on. if word 1 (file 1).equals to word 2 (file 2), file 3 will be the output to show the True and False. Below is the coding but I am stuck when there is no error but giving no output. Am a beginner in JAVA.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test2 {

    private static ArrayList<String> load(String f1) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(f1));
        ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String temp = reader.nextLine();
            String[] sts = temp.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < sts.length; i++) {
                if (sts[i].equals("") && sts[i].equals(" ") && sts[i].equals("\n")) {
                    out.add(sts[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

    private static void write(ArrayList<String> out, String fname) throws IOException {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("out_test2.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < out.size(); i++) {
            writer.write(out.get(i) + "\n");
        }
        writer.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> file1;
        ArrayList<String> file2;
        ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
        file1 = load("IbanDict.txt");
        file2 = load("AFF_outVal.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < file1.size(); i++) {
            String word1 = file1.get(i);
            for (int z = 0; z < file2.size(); z++) {
                if (word1.equalsIgnoreCase(file2.get(z))) {
                    boolean already = false;
                    for (int q = 0; q < out.size(); q++) {
                        if (out.get(q).equalsIgnoreCase(file1.get(i))) {
                            already = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (already == false) {
                        out.add(file1.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        write(out, "out_test2.txt");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you format your code a little better? It's difficult to read. Also - have you debugged to step through each of your loops to see exactly what each ArrayList and/or variable holds when comparing or writing to file3?

Comment: Please edit your post and indent the code to show structure.  It is unreadable in its present state.

Comment: You may want to look into the Levenshtein Distance. There are some Java libraries/algorithms that exist already.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `Scanner` will tokenise your String for you. There is no need to read in a line and tokenise using the `String.split` method; refer [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Secondly, it looks like you have a logic error here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sts.length; i++) {
    if (sts[i].equals("") && sts[i].equals(" ")
            && sts[i].equals("\n"))
       out.add(sts[i]);
}
```

*(assuming I understand what you're trying to do)* it should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sts.length; i++) {
    if (!(sts[i].equals("") && sts[i].equals(" ") && sts[i]
           .equals("\n")))
       out.add(sts[i]);
}
```

This is why you are not seeing any output.

**Note**: This way of matching is error prone and far from optimal (linear); you might have more success with a specialised text parsing language like awk or Python (assuming you're not bound to Java). If you're stuck with Java, an alternative implementation might be to extend `FilterReader/Writer` classes as shown [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/extendsFilterWriterandextendsFilterReader.htm).

Comment: actually, i attempt to check if word 1 exists in the dictionary (file1). Thus, how can I improve the if statement?

Comment: Without really looking at how your solution works, I would suggest trying to negate the logic, i.e. `if(!(sts[i].equals("") && sts[i].equals(" ") && sts[i].equals("\n"))){ ... }`

Comment: yes, there are empty..meaning the if statement must follow the format in the input files?

Comment: @ssaee - so, if `file1` and `file2` are empty, how do you suggest there to be any output? Maybe you should show us your files with gist.

Comment: file1 contains list of words(aka dictionary). whilst, file2 contains also list of words (there are two columns which are STEM and AFFIXES). E.g. file1:
abas
abi
abi

e.g. of file2: INDEX STEM  AFFIXES
_____ ____  _______

1 nyak  NULL na nge
2 angkung  ngel ny nyer
so, i want to check if word (both columns) in file 2 exists in file 1; line by line..

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion for your porblem

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

  private static final Pattern WORD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[\\w']+");

  private static Map<String, Integer> load(final String f1) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(f1));
    Map<String, Integer> out = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
      String tempLine = reader.nextLine();
      if (tempLine != null && tempLine.trim().length() > 0) {
        Matcher matcher = WORD_PATTERN.matcher(tempLine);
        while (matcher.find()) {
          out.put(matcher.group().toLowerCase(), 0);
        }
      }
    }

    return out;
  }

  private static void write(final Map<String, Integer> out, final String fname) throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(fname));
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> word : out.entrySet()) {
      if (word.getValue() == 1) {
        writer.write(word.getKey() + "\n");
      }
    }
    writer.close();
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Integer> file1 = load("file1.txt");
    Map<String, Integer> file2 = load("file2.txt");

    // below for loop will run just one time, so it is much faster
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> file1Word : file1.entrySet()) {
      if (file2.containsKey(file1Word.getKey())) {
        file1.put(file1Word.getKey(), 1);
        file2.put(file1Word.getKey(), 1);
      }
    }

    write(file1, "test1.txt");
    write(file2, "test2.txt");
  }

}
```

Comment: I like the use of the `Pattern` class. I would suggest extending `FilterReader/Writer` as a way to promote encapsulation of this logic.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues I see. One being the redundant splitting on spaces wulfgar.pro pointed out.

Another issue is that `Scanner` will include punctuation, so file1 "I am happy and sad" will not find "happy" if file2 is "You are happy.".

I also changed it to use Sets, since you don't seem to be worried about how many times a word matches. Then use for-each loops to iterate (you are using generics, so you should be able to do for-each loops as well).

So I rewrote the while-loop in the `load` method:

```
private static final Pattern PUNCTUATION_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[\\w']+");

private static Set<String> load(String f1) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(f1));
    Set<String> out = new HashSet<String>();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String tempLine = reader.nextLine();
        if (tempLine != null
                && tempLine.trim().length() > 0) {
            Matcher matcher = PUNCTUATION_PATTERN.matcher(tempLine);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                out.add(tempLine.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

The for-loop in the `main` method can then be simplified to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Set<String> out = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> file1 = load("IbanDict.txt");
    Set<String> file2 = load("AFF_outVal.txt");

    for (String word1 : file1) {
        for (String word2 : file2) {
            if (word1.equalsIgnoreCase(word2)) {
                boolean already = false;
                for (String outStr : out) {
                    if (outStr.equalsIgnoreCase(word1)) {
                        already = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!already) {
                    out.add(word1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    write(out, "out_test2.txt");
}
```

And change the `write` method to iterate, and use `File.separator` to be OS-independent:

```
private static void write(Iterable<String> out, String fname) throws IOException {
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(fname));
    for (String s : out) {
        writer.write(s + File.separator);
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to check if a word from file 2 also exists in file 1. If so print true, if not print false.

The easiest way is probably to make a searchable dataset of all the words in file 1. For each word in file 2 you can then check against the dataset wheter it does or does not contain a word.

The code below does nothing. it creates a array of all words in the file in sts and then you check wheter a word is nothing AND a space AND a newline. if so you add it to an ArrayList. A word will never be all those things and therefore never a word will be added to out.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(f1));
ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
while (reader.hasNext()) {
  String temp = reader.nextLine();    
  String[] sts = temp.split(" ");
  for (int i = 0; i < sts.length; i++) {
    if (sts[i].equals("") && sts[i].equals(" ") && sts[i].equals("\n")) {
      out.add(sts[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Modify your loop here to get a collection of all words by iterating all tokens in your scanner and adding them to the arraylist

```
while (reader.hasNext()) {
 out.add(reader.next());
}
```

Now that you have a arraylist of all words in your dictionary you can start to check.

To see if a word from file 2 is contained in the dictionary you can simply call

```
dictionary.contains(file2.get(i))
```

contains uses the equals method of all Strings in the ArrayList to check if there is a match.

Now if you want to do it line by line you should not make 2 datasets. your dictionary should be a dataset, but for file 2 it is easier to just use the Scanner object.

Read each line from the Scanner. Make sure you use hasNextLine() instead of hasNext() here since hasNextLine() does the check you need for the itteration.

```
line = reader.nextLine();
```

check for each token in the line if it has a match in the list and write true or false + a space if it does

```
String[] splitLine = line.split(" "); 
for(String token: splitLine){    
  writer.write(dictionary.contains(file2.get(i))+" ");
}
```

While checking each line you can write a line to your output file so that the line numbers match.

Your definite code will look something like this:

```
public class Test{

  private static List<String> loadDictionary(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
      out.add(reader.next());
    }
    reader.close();
    return out;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> dictionary;
    dictionary = loadDictionary("IbanDict.txt");

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("AFF_outVal.txt"));
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("out_test2.txt"));

    while(reader.hasNextLine()){
      String line = reader.nextLine();
      String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
      for(String token: tokens){
        writer.write(dictionary.contains(token)+" ");
      }
      writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
  }
}
```